# R2DBC - Oracle Database Support

Tags: oracle, project-reactor, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

I found R2DBC when I was searching reactive relational database drivers, but I couldn't see any driver for
Oracle DB. Does anyone have any information on whether to provide support?

Answer (score 11):

The Oracle R2DBC Driver is now available on GitHub:
https://github.com/oracle/oracle-r2dbc

Comment: any oracle server minimum version requirement to use r2dbc?

Comment: We've verified it with Oracle Database versions 18, 19, and 21.

Answer (score 9):

I confirm that the ADBA work has been terminated however, the upcoming release of the Oracle JDBC drivers furnishes new extensions for Reactive database access. These extensions can also be used with Reactive Streams libraries.
https://events.rainfocus.com/widget/oracle/oow19/catalogcodeone19?search=DEV6323

Regarding Oracle database support for R2DBC, we are looking into this i.e., no firm commitment and no ETA.

Comment: If you need any kind of help or input on the latter, feel free to reach out. The reactive extensions look pretty awesome already and we'd love to see Oracle joining the family of R2DBC implementations!

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/230) thread on spring-data-r2dbc github page,

> The support for oracle with R2DBC is blocked due to the unavailability
>   R2DBC Driver for Oracle

Oracle announced ojdbc20 to carry methods exposing Publisher. But I doubt it'll be incorporated with spring-data-r2dbc, going by this [mail-chain](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdbc-spec-discuss/2019-September/000529.html) where they state fibers are the way forward, async suppoort in ojdbc20 is minimal.

Also avoid using [adba](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-over-adba), Since all the efforts for ADBA have been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there isn't currently any reactive driver being developed at least not actively for Oracle DB.

You can start your investigation here: https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-over-adba

Also see: https://blogs.oracle.com/java/jdbc-next:-a-new-asynchronous-api-for-connecting-to-a-database